# How to avoid double arrow when drawing bended path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am drawing a graph where I need to connect two nodes with bended arrow line.

The problem is that instead of having single arrow on that bended line, I am getting two arrows. The arrow marked with red circle is the one I don't want. How to remove it?

[image: Graph image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}    
\begin{document}
    
\tikzstyle{node}=[
    circle,
    inner sep=2.4mm,
    draw=black,
    line width=0.2mm,
]
    
\tikzstyle{linea}=[
    draw=black,
    line width=0.34mm,
    -triangle 60
]
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]     
\node (n1) at (1, 0.5) {};
\node (n2) [node] at (1, 2) {A};
\node (n3) [node] at (1, 4) {x};    
\path [linea] (n1) -- (n2);
\path [linea] (n2) -- (n3);
\path [linea, bend left] (n3.west) edge (n2.west);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Replace `edge` by `to`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/123129))
- add `\usetikzlibrary{automata}` and use option `state` for the nodes
- add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` for relative positioning
- minimized example
- added comparison between `edge` and `to`

  - see also [tikz manual "17.12 Connecting Nodes: Using the Edge Operation"](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.12)
  - "`edge` temporarily suspends the construction of the current path and a new path *p* is constructed" (red)
  - `to` adds stuff to the path (blue)
- If you want to use `egde` you shouldn't use `draw` (see lower image).
- If you want to use `to` you should use `draw` (see upper image).
- If you only need to connect *two* nodes, the usual way would be to use:

  ```
  \draw[linea] (a) to[bend right] (b); % with bend
  \draw[linea] (a) -- (b); % without bend
  ```

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    linea/.style={
        draw,
        -triangle 60
    },
]
    \node [state] (a) {a};
    \node [state, right=of a] (b) {b};
    \node [state, right=of b] (c) {c};
    \path [linea, bend left, red] (a.north) edge (b.north) edge node[above]{\texttt{edge}} (c.north);
    \path [linea, blue, bend right] (a.south) to (b.south) to node[below]{\texttt{to}} (c.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\verb|draw| and \verb|\path ...| = \verb|\draw ...|

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    linea/.style={
        -triangle 60
    },
]
    \node [state] (a) {a};
    \node [state, right=of a] (b) {b};
    \node [state, right=of b] (c) {c};
    \path [linea, bend left, red] (a.north) edge (b.north) edge node[above]{\texttt{edge}} (c.north);
    \path [linea, blue, bend right] (a.south) to (b.south) to node[below]{\texttt{to}} (c.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
no \verb|draw| and \verb|\path|

\end{document}
```